# How to write data to my App document after take a photo from Camera?

Tags: ios, iphone, image, save, nsdocumentdirectory

It's possible to save the shooting pictures into the photo library through apply for `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:` after took pictures by camera.

But I don't want to save the picture into the photo library and wanna to save them into my owned APP catalog.  Currently, I can get the `NSdata` and `Metadata`.

Is there anybody could advise me what I should do?  Really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

To save the `NSdata` to your own app documents folder, use the below code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentDirPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ImageName.png"];
[yourNSdata writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

You can read it after using the below code,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];
NSData *myImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
UIImage *savedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:myImageData];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the metadata lose. I want write NSData and Metadata to one file.